# Windows 10 not recognizing python file type

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have Python 3.7 installed on two windows 10 machines. I am trying to run a mut script on both machines, however it only successfully runs on one machine. The key difference that I saw was on the machine where it ran successfully. The mut script has a file type of Python File where as on the machine where it was not running at all the mut script has a file type of PY File. I am not sure how to make windows associate .py with the file type Python File instead of PY File. Has anyone come across this problem and have a solution for this?

Comment: The default installation should associate .py files with the Python Launcher. Try to repair both the Python and Python Launcher installations, and then for a .py script icon in Explorer, select "open with" -> "choose another app". Select the "Python" app with a rocket on its icon, and enable the option to "always use this app ...".

Comment: Repairing both the Python and Python launcher fixed my problem. Thank you for the solution!